# insert elements between reads in vector in theads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

Below sample crashes
while thread print is reading the vector and in between the thread insert gets turn and inserts some elements after switching back to thread print program carashes , how to overcome this problem

```
// Thread_vector.cpp 
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


//thead insert
using namespace std;
void insert_elements(vector<int> & v) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        v.push_back(i);
        cout << " : inserted - " << i << "  ";
    }

}
//thead print

void print_elements(vector<int> & vec) {
    for (auto & p:vec)
    {
        std::cout << p << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> b;
    thread ins(insert_elements, std::ref(b));
    thread prn(print_elements, std::ref(b));
    ins.join();
    prn.join();

    return 0;
}
```

scenario:

1. don't know the number of elements to insert in advance
2. want to do parallel read and insert
3. once read thread started insert elements between reads

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::shared_lock` for read thread and `std::unique_lock` or `std::lock_guard` for insert thread.

[cppreference:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock)

> The class shared_lock is a general-purpose shared mutex ownership
>   wrapper allowing deferred locking, timed locking and transfer of lock
>   ownership. Locking a shared_lock locks the associated shared mutex in
>   shared mode (to lock it in exclusive mode, std::unique_lock can be
>   used)

```
std::shared_mutex rwmutex;

void insert_elements(std::vector<int> & v) {
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> read_lock(rwmutex); // or std::lock_guard
    //change actions
}

void print_elements(vector<int> & vec) {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> write_lock(rwmutex);
    //read actions
}
```

Comment: using above shared_mutex logic , it works either read all and write all  or write all  and read  all. But i what to switch the threads between the for loop in the thread function 
1. start read for loop print_elements ,  2. switc back to insert elements  3. then switch back complete read for loop in thread

Comment: Because sometimes reallocation happens, try to remember your number and get the following